# Customize Metric visualization

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I'm looking for a way to customize Kibana4 metric visualization as follows.
Say, you want to display average humidity.

In vanilla Kibana, the field looks like this.

```
49.7
Average humidity
```

And I want to add unit(%) and hide legend(Average humidity).

```
49.7 %
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a [field formatter](https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-1-field-formatters) would help?